# difference between calling command directly and using keybinding

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm new to elisp, so please forgive me if the following approach is totally clumsy.

In the team I'm currently working with, there is an usual convention of closing python blocks with a `pass` statement (if they aren't ended by closing keywords like `else` or `except` or such). While unusual, this has the advantage that one can always recover the original indentation of the program if it is unintentionally changed (using emacs `indent-region`).

To get existing code in line with this convention, I wrote a small elisp function:

```
(defun python-check-indent ()
 "Check if automatic indentation changes current indent, insert pass keyword if it does."
 (interactive)
 (move-beginning-of-line 1)
 (skip-chars-forward " ")
 (if
  (< 0
     (let (original)
      (setq original (point))
      (indent-for-tab-command)
      (- (point) original)
      )
     )
  (progn
   (insert "pass")
   (newline)
   (indent-for-tab-command)
   )
 )
 (next-line)
)


(global-set-key (kbd "C-`") 'python-check-indent)
```

The idea is simply to test whether hitting TAB would change the indentation, and insert a `pass` statement in that case. To facilitate processing longer blocks of code, it then advances to the next line.

When I run it using `M-x python-check-indent`, it does what I want (except that it moves around empty lines slightly), also when running it repeatedly to process several lines.  However, when I run it repeatedly using the C-` keybinding, it starts messing up the code from the second invocation on.

So here are my questions: What is the difference between invoking a command with `M-x ...` and using its keybinding? And how could I change the function to be not affected by this difference?

emacs-version: GNU Emacs 23.3.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin, NS apple-appkit-1038.35) of 2011-03-10 on black.porkrind.org

(edit) current workaround: I'm now wrapping it inside a keyboard-macro, so it's "bound" to C-x e, and behaves properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general rule is that it is best to avoid complex interactive
commands in your functions because they could be affected by all sorts
of options.

```
(defun python-check-indent ()
  "Check if automatic indentation changes current indent, insert pass keyword if it does."
  (interactive)
  (goto-char (line-beginning-position))
  (skip-chars-forward " ")
  (when (< 0
           (let (original)
             (setq original (point))
             (python-indent-line)
             (- (point) original)))
    (insert "pass\n")
    (python-indent-line))
  (forward-line))
```

However, even this is probably not good because `python-indent-line`'s behavior depends on `last-command` and `python-indent-trigger-commands`.  I think it would be best if you replaced the first invocation of `python-indent-line` with the code which computes the target indentation instead of actually indenting, something like `(nth python-indent-current-level python-indent-levels)`.

PS. If you still have problems, I suggest that you use [`edebug`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Edebug.html) and step through the function.

Comment: hi, that rule makes a lot of sense, but unfortunately I still get different behavior when I invoke the function using the keybinding, while it works correctly when using M-x python-check-indent.

Comment: I got it! I just needed to also replace the other indent-for-tab-command by python-indent-line. Thanks so much!